# How to only print get data from console log arrarys that have a sub item with a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a movie website and with a movie id, I get lots of info about a movie that I can display as HTML. When I go to get videos for a specific movie however it returns many arrary items each containing an item called `type=""`, where this could equal either Featurette, Clip or Trailer. How can I only print out the array items with the `type="Trailer"`.

Here is the javascript code for getting a movie with the id of 451048:

```
 axios
       .get(
           "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieId + "/videos?api_key=1350e4528ff8559ef2b0fa6679f97d84&language=en-US"
       )
       .then((response) => {
           console.log(response);
           //puts the array of movies into the variable
           let videos = response.data.results;
           let output = "";
           $.each(videos, (index, video) => {
               output += `
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well text-center">
                        <iframe width="420" height="315"
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.key}">
                            <h5>${video.type}</h5>
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                `;
           });
           //prints the movies on the div with the class movies
           $("#videos").html(output);
       })
       .catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });
```

And this is the console log:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/451048/videos?a…y=1350e4528ff8559ef2b0fa6679f97d84&language=en-US", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data:
id: 451048
results: Array(7)
 0:
  id: "60e83f52b76cbb00461e9440"
  iso_639_1: "en"
  iso_3166_1: "US"
  key: "aYSy8guUUV0"
  name: "Jungle Cruise Featurette - Big Adventure (2021) | Movieclips Trailers"
  official: false
  published_at: "2021-07-07T17:51:17.000Z"
  site: "YouTube"
  size: 1080
  type: "Featurette"
[[Prototype]]: Object
 1:
  id: "60e62f666bdec3004615a7b2"
  iso_639_1: "en"
  iso_3166_1: "US"
  key: "W1vKz21UvX4"
  name: "Disney’s Jungle Cruise | July 30"
  official: true
  published_at: "2021-07-01T21:22:30.000Z"
  site: "YouTube"
  size: 1080
  type: "Trailer"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

As you can see, I only want console data from the above javascript of `let movies = response.data.results;` to be console array's that have the `type="Trailer"`

Comment: `let movies = response.data.results.filter(m => m.type === "Trailer");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh commented the correct answer (I don't know how to highlight his comment because I'm new to StackOverflow) which was:

```
let videos = response.data.results.filter(m => m.type === "Trailer");
```

Not sure what the `m` is in the code (it would be great if someone could explain it to me)

Comment: I assume `m` is short for `movie` as the `results` you're filtering is a list of movies.

Comment: That was my intent. I think `movieTrailers` might be a better name for the result of the filter than either "movies" or "videos".

Answer (score 1):

You can use keys to help traverse through a JSON.

```
for(int i =0;i < response.data.results.length;i++){

if(response.data.results[i]["type"] === "Trailer"){

console.log(response.data.results[i]);

}

}
```